# Get 2D intersection of a plan and an arbitrary volume

Tags: sage

In order to get the intersection of a plan and an arbitrary volume in Sage, I did this :

```
eq_object = -(cos(x) + cos(y) + cos(z))
eq_knife = 3*x+2*y+1*z 
object = implicit_plot3d(eq_object, (x,-4,4), (y,-4,4), (z,-4,4), color='orchid')
knife = implicit_plot3d(eq_knife == 0, (x,-4,4), (y,-4,4), (z,-4,4), color='black')
```

But the intersection, given by `solve` are the equations itself:

```
intersection = solve([eq_object, eq_knife], [x, y, z])
intersection

>> [3*x + 2*y + z, -cos(x) - cos(y) - cos(z)]
```

What do I do wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

You may have wanted this:

```
solve(eq_object==eq_knife, [x, y, z])
```

which gives `[]` the empty solution set, probably because this is just too hard.  These aren't algebraic systems, once you slap the `cos` in there.

Even the very simple

```
solve([cos(x),x],[x])
```

gives this kind of response, although in this case `cos(x)=0` and `x=0` are not possible together.  But what we "really" want,

```
solve([cos(x)==x],[x])
```

just gives the original back, because there is no "nice" way to write this. It happens.

Edit: Maybe you wanted an implicit plot, then?

```
var('y')
implicit_plot(-(cos(x) + cos(y) + cos(-3*x-2*y)),(x,-5,5),(y,-5,5),figsize=4)
```

[image]

I think I did this one right.

Comment: The thing is it does't all the time work, I need a generic method for that and in the example : the intersection of a sphere (centered on the origin, radius 2) and a plan defined by the origin and the normal vector `[1,1,1]`. The equation of the intersection is `(x+y)^2 + x^2 + y^2 == 4` which is not the equation of a circle.

Comment: I'm not sure why this wouldn't work all the time.  If you implicitly plot anything it should work okay.  I just solved for `z` and plugged it in - if you have a plane (other than one with no `z`) that should work fine, and you can even automate it using `solve()` if you really have to.

Comment: I opened a [new question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2357188/intersection-of-a-sphere-and-a-plan-projected-on-the-plan) because the equation is correct, I spoke too fast before. It's just that the equation we get is a projection of a circle over the `xy` plan so we get an ellipse sometimes.